# Residential Real Estate Appraisal

Tags: regression, modeling, small-sample

Appraisers use adjustments to derive the value of a subject property.  For example, if a similar house has 100 more square feet of living space, and sold for $210,000, we deduct the value of the space to indicate a value for the subject.

If the adjustment is made at $\$50/ \text{ft}^2,$ the indication is $\$205,000$.  If the adjustment is $\$100/ \text{ft}^2,$ the indication is $\$200,000$. Traditionally, this has been done by experience.  Now we are expected to support the adjustment with regression.

What sample size is required?  Is it better to have fewer, more similar properties or more properties that are less similar?

Comment: I know enough basic regression analysis to help address your question, but I'm not certain I understand the variables here. When you say "Traditionally, this has done by experience," I, the reader, am left a little lost. Are there two (or more) variables you're trying to compare? The reasoning you've used so far in your question is just basic (valid) algebra; is the adjustment rate (dollars per square feet) variable? Is the house price the response?